# Should edits be "rolled back" if users update/change their questions with a given answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I see it quite often that users post a question. After there's an answer that fits, they revise the question with the content of that answer/suggestion and ask another (different) question on top/instead. In this case all answers already posted will get meaningless.

Here's an example:
[Easy: Addclass removeClass hasClass issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388476/easy-addclass-removeclass-hasclass-issue#13388520)

What's the best practice to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any edit that changes the question should be rolled back, but for a question without answers, sometimes I think the OP can be given a little leeway as long as they aren't trying to get around a question ban and/or completely changing the question.

However, **any** edit to a question, other than clarifying the original question, that invalidates any answer should be rolled back and a comment should be left indicating what they did wrong.  Sometimes it is possible to edit the question in such a way as to integrate the new info added by the OP without invaliding answers and the editor should try to make an effort to do that.

It's not the same as your example, but I think the resolution is still the same, but in this question, [trouble adding calculated variables c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12755574/250725), I did exactly that.  The OP, in an attempt to provide more code requested, removed what was wrong with his code originally and invalidated virtually every answer.  So I rolled back the question, and then tried to incorporate the new code in such a way that kept up with the original spirit of the question, did not invalidate answers, and still helped the OP get the answers he needed.  Based on his response to my comment when I explained what I did, he seemed satisified, so I tried to use this as a guide for doing this in the future.

I think most of the time, the OP doesn't know and usually is accommodating to the site's policies, so you shouldn't meet much resistance.

Answer (score 1):

If the workflow is like the following, then the question should not be changed, and any change should be rolled back.

1. OP asks a question.
2. Somebody answers that question.
3. The OP reports in the question s/he tried what suggested in the question, and that s/he has a new question about that.

In such case, the question is changed so much that the given answer is not anymore valid.
The answer is what caused the OP to ask the new answer, but follow-up questions should be new questions. The fact the user got an answer for what s/he asked doesn't mean s/he can re-use the question for asking a new question. That is valid even if there is just an answer.